# angularjs set default value ng-model using value from another ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-ng-init

I would like to pass the value of an ng-model that the user sets in a another form field select options to another ng-model as initial value in the same form.

In this example, I want the ng-init value of `myModel.fieldB` to be the value `myModel.fieldA.subfield`, this is successfully evaluating in the value of the span element, but not in the ng-model for `myModel.fieldB`, meaning that nothing is happening in `ng-init="myModel.fieldB = myModel.fieldA.subfield"`. 
However when I pass string literal values, it works, for example `ng-init="myModel.fieldB = 'some example'"`

```
<span class="form-group" ng-model="myModel.fieldB" ng-init="myModel.fieldB = myModel.fieldA.subfield">{{myModel.fieldA.subfield}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when you pass the literal value it's constant and not going to change but when you pass the variable value like this `ng-init="myModel.fieldB = myModel.fieldA.subfield"` (myModel.fieldB) it will be set **only once at the creation time of this element** with whatever value inside (myModel.fieldA.subfield), so to overcome this you can use ng-change on the select element as below:

```
<select data-ng-model="myModel.fieldB" ng-change="myModel.fieldA.subfield = myModel.fieldB">
   <option value="option1">option1</option>
   <option value="option1">option1</option>
</select>
<span class="form-group">{{myModel.fieldA.subfield}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply make use of `ng-change` directive for your select `input` and assign the value of `myModel.fieldA.subfield` to the `myModel.fieldB` ?

Just like this:

```
ng-change="assignValue(myModel.fieldA.subfield)"
```

Then:

```
$scope.assignValue = function(val) {
    if (val) {
      $scope.myModel.fieldB = val;
    }
  }
```

Here's a working [plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/7y094sf7/)